# Why my post method is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

my method $_POST works fine in my other form but in here my $_POST not working.
Here is my form

```
<h3 class="page-title">Medicine Inventory: Add Stock</h3>
      <form method="POST" action="PHP/action_insertaddstock.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">

          </div>

          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="medicine_id" class="control-label">Medicine ID (Required) :</label>
                <select class="form-control select2" required="" id="medicine_id" name="medicine_id">
                  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please select --</option>
                   <?php foreach($medicines as $val) : ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $val['id']; ?>"><?php echo $val['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="qty" class="control-label">Quantity (Required) :</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="" required="" name="qty" type="number" id="qty">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="xdate" class="control-label">Expiry Date (Required) :</label>
                <input class="form-control " placeholder="" required="" name="xdate" id="xdate">
                <p class="help-block"></p>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" >Save</button>
      </form>
```

and my action is here

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once('CONFIG/config.php');
include_once('CONFIG/db.php');

$Med_id =  $_POST['medicine_id'];
$Qty = $_POST['qty'];
$Xdate =  $_POST['xdate'];
$Timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");




if(empty($Med_id) || empty($Qty) || empty($Xdate) || empty($Timestamp)){
      header("Location: ../added_stock.php?add=empty");
     exit();    
 }else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO medicines_addeds (qty, xdate, created_at, 
 med_id) VALUES ('$Qty', '$Xdate', '$Timestamp', '$Med_id')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            header("Location: ../added_stock.php?add=success");
            exit();


}

} else {
 header("Location: ../MIAdd_medicine.php");
 exit();
}
```

the query works fine because i tried to put value in the variables and it insert in my database but when i tried the $_POST it does nothing it run succesfully but my database is empty. Please Help me

table structure is here

```
1   idPrimary   int(11)             No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT   
2   qty int(11)                     Yes NULL             
3   xdate   date                    Yes NULL             
4   created_at  timestamp           Yes NULL            
5   edited_at   timestamp           Yes NULL             
6   deleted_at  timestamp           Yes NULL            
7   med_id  int(11)                 Yes NULL
```

Comment: share your medicines_addeds table structure of database

Comment: Share your DB table structure and try to watch if all post data are comming with var_dump($_POST)

Comment: i include the table structure sir

Comment: The table is called medicines_addeds without typo?

Comment: yes @Eji ------

Comment: Just after your declaration of Timestamp, could you add `var_dump($_POST); exit;` and show the result?

Comment: i think the problem is with the `sql connection`, please check it once again, i tried your code `$_POST` is working fine, and i am  able to display query correctly.

Comment: array(4) { ["medicine_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["qty"]=> string(2) "45" ["xdate"]=> string(10) "03/13/2019" ["submit"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: i have my other form and have the same config and it works fine

Comment: `$conn` is the variable name? are you sure?

Comment: yes i just check it

Comment: xdate is not in the right format. You are inserting a DD/MM/YYYY format date but it should be in YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: do one thing remove `single quotes` from `$qty` and `$med_id` as they are `int`, if you have `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` enabled it will not allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your xdate with

```
$Xdate = date('y/m/d', strtotime($_POST(xdate))
```

Comment: No problem, but do as Ash-b said. It could became problematic :] When it's a Int, send an Int without ' or "